# tar: behavior when missing files

Tags: tar

If extracting with GNU tar with an explicit list of files like this:

```
tar xf archive.tar file_a file_b file_c
```

what is the behavior if `file_b` is missing (i.e. `archive.tar` only contains `file_a` and `file_c`)? Are `file_a` and `file_c` guaranteed to be extracted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the other files will be extracted.

Each file is extracted when it is encountered in the tar file. When tar finds the files `file_a` and `file_c`, it has not way to determine whether there will be a `file_b` after that or not. Remember, the name tar is derived from tape archive, it reads the archive from start to end, without seeking.